# Release build issue

Tags: actionscript-3

Hi this is my code but when i release build then it does not read the files in src  folder

please help

```
[Bindable][Embed (source="../src/camera_para.dat", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
private var cam_params:Class;


[Bindable][Embed (source="../src/marker_ge.pat", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
private var marker:Class;
```

Comment: ok this code does not work when i run it

Comment: [Embed (source="../src/camera_para.dat", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
  private var cam_params:Class;
  
  
  [Embed (source="../src/marker_ge.pat", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
  private var marker:Class;

Comment: Sounds like you're solving your own problem. What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

In the release build of a SWF, all of the metatags (`[Embed]` etc) are stripped out unless you specifically keep them in.

If you add the line:

```
-keep-as3-metadata+=Embed,SomeOtherTag,EtcEtc
```

to your compiler options it should work. If you use FlashDevelop, you can do this in Project > Properties > Compiler Options > Additional Compiler Options. Just click the little + and add the line above on a new line